# using container from cloud functions in cloud run jobs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

I am quite new to gcp and I created a small test function in cloud functions like so:

```
import functions_framework
import dask.dataframe as dd

@functions_framework.http
def hello_http(request):
    """HTTP Cloud Function.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): The request object.
        <https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#incoming-request-data>
    Returns:
        The response text, or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using `make_response`
        <https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.make_response>.
    """
    id="ok"
    return id
```

I tested the function on cloud shell using:

```
curl -m 36230 -X POST https://some-url.cloudfunctions.net/index-firestore-2 -H "Authorization: bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{}'
```

and it spits out the correct output as expected.

Now, I see that in cloud run, there is a `job` which takes in a container and runs this for a longer duration. So, I created a job, where I specified `'{}'` as my argument for the container. When I run this job it always seems to error out. So,

```
Leave blank to use the entry point command defined in the container image: <left blank>
Arguments passed to the entry point command: '{}' #also tried {} and leaving it blank
```

but it seems to say argument is not recognised when I give in '{}' or '{}'. If I leave it blank, nothing happens. The exact error is:

`Error: Got unexpected extra argument ({})`

Wondering what is going on since it works on cloud function and as far as iam aware the v2 version of cloud function is just an absttraction over cloud run :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to review the services and what you want to do. Let me summarize (and simplify) and you will understand your misunderstanding

Cloud Functions is a convenient service that take your piece of code that handle a Request (in case of HTTP functions). Then, it adds a Flask layer and package the whole thing in a container. Then the container is served on Cloud Functions services (in gen1

Cloud Run standard serves containers. You can do the same thing as the Cloud Functions but you have to write your how Flask webserver and your Dockerfile to create the container. You MUST expose a webserver in the container which is deployed on Cloud Run service

Cloud Run Jobs also serves container. But this time, there is no API access. It's only a script, a job. No webserver and HTTP request. When the container exits (end of the job) the running instance is stoped

---

Therefore, serving container with webserver (made with Cloud Functions or other container builder) in Cloud Run Jobs does not make sense. The exposed port will be never reachable, and the container will never end (up to the job timeout, and the kill).

---

Review your design and what you want to achieve.